# Css query to select inline-text separated by some element

Tags: html, css

How do you select text content via CSS query separated by some element, say you have:

```
Some text content
<div>Another content</div>
And additional content
```

And you would like to select `Some text content` and `And additional content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can refer to the `inline-text` from the CSS because you do not have nothing to link with it. You can apply some styles to the container and then add an `id` for your text inside the `div` to make it different.

In this case, I take the root element `*` but the behaviour would be the same if you wrap your code in a container.

```css
*{
  color: red;
}

#text{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
Some text content
<div id="text">Another content</div>
And additional content
```

**EDIT:** You can create the content with the different styles with pseudo class.

```css
*{
  color: red;
}

div:before{
  content: "Some text content";
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}

div:after{
  content: "And additional content";
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">Another content</div>
```

But in this case, you do not have the content created, you create it depending of your `div`.

Comment: @Lu4 I do not think so. I think the best approach is to wrap the content in a container and then style both the container and the text inside the div.

Comment: @Lu4 Look my new edit. You can do it, but creating the inline-text in the pseudo class. I had to put the content as a block to put it in the next line as in your example, but maybe it is what you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this highlight variation

```css
        .paragraph-block {
            color: #aaa;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        .highlighted {
            color: green;
        }

        .highlighted.medium {
            /* color: blue; */ /* you can also add this if you want to change the color */
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .highlighted.large {
            /* color: blue; */ /* you can also add this if you want to change the color */
            font-size: 28px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="paragraph-block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="highlighted">Pellentesque</span> vitae justo et sapien ultrices bibendum eget pretium risus. Curabitur tincidunt egestas mauris nec tempus. Vivamus auctor rhoncus sem a ornare. Fusce porttitor id mi sagittis malesuada. Etiam iaculis urna at sem pulvinar, in mattis libero facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin egestas convallis porttitor. Fusce eget mauris lacus. Duis pellentesque dolor sed ex venenatis, et dictum mi tincidunt. Vivamus aliquam, felis quis semper pulvinar, felis elit mattis quam, vel imperdiet eros mi in tellus.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="paragraph-block">
        <p>Donec erat arcu, sagittis eu ullamcorper eget, interdum et dui. Duis <span class="highlighted medium">vulputate</span> ligula vitae sagittis malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Integer quis urna vel ligula convallis placerat ut vel ipsum. Aenean pellentesque ante et augue dictum iaculis. Pellentesque quis odio vitae nibh sodales ultrices ut ac risus. Cras congue pulvinar enim, nec tincidunt nisi. Pellentesque neque lorem, iaculis non purus varius, varius pharetra quam. Vivamus sed lobortis diam, id vestibulum velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam aliquet, leo a sollicitudin porttitor, quam enim pellentesque magna, vitae rutrum enim tellus et mi. Cras ornare congue ligula sed porttitor. Sed eget viverra nisl.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="paragraph-block">
        <p>Sed efficitur sodales velit, vel dignissim dolor ullamcorper id. <span class="highlighted large">Quisque quis quam eget ligula</span> tincidunt ornare fermentum sed nulla. Suspendisse placerat, purus sed consectetur pharetra, orci tortor consectetur lorem, eget feugiat quam metus eu nisi. Nulla arcu nulla, imperdiet ut venenatis eu, aliquet vitae libero. Phasellus sed consequat dolor. Sed accumsan purus non arcu dictum semper. Praesent ac ultricies metus. Donec sit amet nulla a neque ullamcorper facilisis porttitor gravida ligula. Donec eleifend id lorem nec auctor. Aliquam laoreet vulputate venenatis. Vivamus eget pulvinar lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut consectetur nibh massa, non aliquam orci rhoncus in. Vestibulum id nibh non sem aliquet imperdiet non sed elit. Morbi hendrerit ut orci a faucibus. Quisque nulla massa, lobortis pellentesque nulla vestibulum, elementum gravida dolor.</p>
    </div>
```